# Oracle APEX - Tables missing on the create data load page in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am using ORAcle APEX version 21.1.1.
I was trying to create a data load definition, by going to Shared Components --> Data Load Defnitions. But when I try to add the table 'XXUA_TEST_AG', I get error that the Table does not exist  : Although the table do exist in the APPS schema.

[image]

And also, If I see in the object browser, I am able to find this table :

[image]

So, my question is why is the table missing when I add it in data definitions. Do I need to do something different for this table, to make it accessible ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,
Abha

Comment: Did you **type** table name (while creating data load definition), or did you **select** it from list of values (button right to "Table name" item)?

Comment: I tried both ways.. from the list of values and by typing. In fact if I search in the list of values, no tables are being shown, although there definitely are many tables in my APPS schema !

Comment: What does the following query return? `select object_name, object_type, owner from all_objects where upper(object_name) like '%XXUA_TEST_AG%';`

Comment: Thank you for taking your time. I ran the query , and gives 2 rows as result : "XXUA_TEST_AG TABLE SYS "     &    " XXUA_TEST_AG    TABLE APPS "

Comment: Strange ... one more test, please: was table created with double quotes and - accidentally - there's space at the end. What does `select '#' || object_name || '#' ... ` return?

Comment: Strange Indeed :(. The table was not created with double quotes, hence htere is no space also. The result of select '#' || object_name || '#', object_type, owner from all_objects where upper(object_name) like '%XXUA_TEST_AG%';  is :   #XXUA_TEST_AG# TABLE SYS
#XXUA_TEST_AG# TABLE APPS

Comment: (Sorry, I was absent). Just for testing purposes: what happens if you select some other table from the same schema? Don't continue with the Wizard, just test whether other tables also result in the same error message.

Comment: (Sorry I was absent too) It gives the same error. Actually, when I search in the list of values, I do not see ANY table for that schema. I tried for another schema also, and I find very few tables in the list. I do not really understand what could be the reason ? In object browser , I can see all the tables for both the schemas, but not while data load?

Comment: I though that "tables" you see are actually **synonyms** or **materialized views**, but - query you ran says they are **tables**. Huh. Try to query - again - ALL_OBJECTS (or USER_OBJECTS) and compare data you see. What are the differences between "very few tables" and the rest (especially XXUA_TEST_AG)?

Comment: So, I do not see any tables for 'APPS' schema but I can see few tables (eg. 'XXUA_CUST_ROLES') for 'XXUA' schema.
I compared my table XXUA_TEST_AG (in APPS schema) and XXUA_CUST_ROLES (in XXUA schema), but I couldnot see any major differnece there.  The only differnce is that there is a synonym for XXUA_CUST_ROLE IN APPS. But I tried to create my table in XXUA schema and added a synonym in APPS. That also didn't help :(

Comment: OK, but - if your Apex application works with APPS schema, why don't you create table there?

Comment: No, I am creating my table in APPS schema only.  But that is the problem, none of my tables from APPS schema are visible in the data load . Do you know if there has to be any specific requirement for a table to be able to pop up in the list of values ? In my opinion, any table from the selected schema should be visible..but that clearly is not the case here..

Comment: Exactly, I expect that too. If workspace "sees" APPS schema, I don't know why data load wouldn't see its tables. I tried that in my Apex - works OK, I see all tables from that schema.

Comment: hmm..a mystery for me in that case..May be there is some generic setting to be done somewhere so that all tables are picked up..nevermind..I will look further. Thanks a lot for taking out your time..

Comment: You're welcome; I'm just sorry & puzzled why it won't work properly for you. Unfortunately, I don't have any other idea ...